# move_uploaded_file() only uploads small files

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to implement a small file upload on a web portal. I found this solution on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
<form action='action.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: 
    <input name="userfile" type="file"/>
    <!-- hidden input fields to sent variables to action.ph -->
    <innput type="hidden" name='casenumber' id="caseForFileUpload" />
    <input type="hidden" name='key' id="keyForFileUpload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" name="uploadfiles"/>
</form>
```

and this is the relevant part of `action.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadfiles'])){
    if(!empty($_FILES)){
        $target_dir = "upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        $fileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if($fileType == "pdf"){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_file)){
                echo "<br><br>File uploaded";
            }else{
                echo "<br><br>File could not be uploaded";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works well for small files <150KB, but fails for files larger than that and I don't know why this is happening.

Relevant info from `php.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
```

So it really should work for files that are larger than 150KB. There is no message in the PHP log and no `.htaccess` is used that may override these settings.

Where else can I look to track down this behavior or how else can I implement a file upload to allow file sizes for up to 2MB?

PS: Please also note that the server is still running with PHP 5.2.17 and that it's not in my power to update it to a newer version.

Comment: `name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000"` <<< look at that closely. That is 30,000 bytes. As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php  *"The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes)"*. Either remove that input, or increase it.

Comment: AS @Fred-ii- already told. Change the value of the hidden input to 2000000.

Comment: Couple of other things also needs to configure.. plz chk this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615312/no-error-when-uploading-a-really-big-file-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii-: As soon as I hit the "post" button I noticed that `MAX_FILE_SIZE` and was like "Wait a minute... is that BYTES?". Turns out: Yes, it is. Please post you comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @waka Glad to see everything worked out, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I guess it's a clear case of `RTFMC`: Read the f* manual carefully.

Comment: @waka I wouldn't have said "that" TBH ;-) I used to years ago, but that was no longer well-taken. So I just visit the manual(s) and quote (a) line(s) from it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As request by the OP:

`name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000"`

That is 30,000 bytes. As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

> *"The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes)"*.

Either remove that input, or increase it.